# The proper way to use parameters/arguments in c#?

Tags: c#, parameters, arguments

I have an app that gets 3 main parameters: sum, substract, print. If one of this parameters is given the app calls the methods: sum for sum, substract for substract, print for print.

Calling with parameters all examples:

```
myapp.exe sum 1 2
myapp.exe substract 3
myapp.exe print whatever
```

This is my actual code which doesn't work

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program package = new Program();

        if (args[0] == @"sum")
        {

            package.sum(args[1], args[2]);
        }

        else if (args[0] == @"substract")
        {
            package.substract(args[1]);
        }

        else if (args[0] == @"print")
        {
            package.print(args[1]);
        }

        else
            Console.Write("Invalid Parameters");
    }
```

But this is the error I get when debugging:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in myapp.exe
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in myapp.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the best way to work with parameters ?

Comment: Step through your code.

Comment: The code looks OK, where do you provide the parameters (arguments) when debugging?

Comment: Take a look to Command Line Parser by Giacomo Stelluti Scala http://commandline.codeplex.com/documentation .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are assuming that the program is always called with the proper number of parameters. Specifically, that

- At least one parameter is present
- When the initial parameter is `sum` or `print`, two parameters are present
- When the initial parameter is `add`, three parameters are present

This is not always correct, depending on what the user enters. You need to add code checking for the length of the `args` array before referencing its elements:

```
if (args.Length < 2) {
    Console.Error.Write("Invalid Parameters");
    return;
}
if (args[0] == @"sum" && args.Length == 3) {
    ...
}
... // The rest of your code can assume that there's at least two args
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is great but I feel like there is a little more to this answer than just the number of variables.

I find that the following type of solution works best for me when in need of a somewhat robust argument solution:

```
if (args.Length > 0)
{
    if (args.Contains<string>("--help"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("appname [--debug] [--bootstrap <bootstrap name>]");
        Console.WriteLine(" --debug       Runs \"appname\" in debug mode.")
        Console.WriteLine(" --bootstrap   If no bootstrap name is provided the default \"AppName v1.2\" will be used.")
        Console.WriteLine("")
    }
    //simple single argument passed to application
    if (args.Contains<string>("--debug")) 
    {
        DEBUG_ON = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Found argument: --debug");
    }
    //more complex relational argument passed to application
    if (args.Contains<string>("--bootstrap")) 
    {
        int bootstrapLoc = Array.IndexOf<string>(args, "--bootstrap");
        //always check that there is one more argument in the array
        if(args.Length > bootstrapLoc + 1)
        {
            string bootstrapArg = args[bootstrapLoc + 1];
            //this is where you would do your error checking against the second argument, ex: determine that it is what is expected
            if (bootstrapArg != null && bootstrapArg != "")
            {
                this.MongoDBInstallName = bootstrapArg;
                Console.WriteLine("Using the passed bootstrap arg: " + bootstrapArg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are definitely better ways to do this and this by no means is fool proof but I just wanted to add some more detail to this question.